# C++ create ifstream/ofstream in a class, associated with pre-made text file

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I am having a problem associating an `ifstream read` and `ofstream print` to a pre-made text file called finances.txt. This is within a class called `Data`. So far, this is what I've tried:

I declared `ifstream read` and `ofstream print` in the class header file. Then, in the cpp file:

```
Data::Data(string n, string d)
:name(n),
date(d)
read(name)
print(name)
{
    cout << "name = " << name << endl;
    read.open(name);
    print.open(name);
    //...
}
```

I also tried this, without declaring anything in the header:

```
Data::Data(string n, string d)
:name(n),
date(d)
{
    ifstream read(name);
    ofstream print(name);
    //...
```

And just different variations of this kind of thing. The syntax is always correct in the sense that I don't get any errors, but whenever it runs, it acts like the file doesn't exist and creates a new one named `finances.txt`, which in turn erases all of the text that was in the original. I have done this correctly before and just can't remember what I did and what I am doing incorrectly here.

Comment: You need to open the file for appending... search for that and you'll find the necessary options to append to the `ofstream` constructor.

Comment: Having a file simultaneously open for reading and writing on two different fstreams is a bit dicey. I'm not sure what will happen here, it may depend on your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused as to what exactly you are trying to do?
Are you trying to append to the file? Because when you call
`ofstream print(name)` you are writing over the file that you are reading in.

So if you want to append to that same file you have to add.
`fstream::app` in the declaration of the ofstream

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit a litte confused about this comment.